# Create a custom log level

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I only log only `info` logs to my log, and suppress all other information, namely the database queries?

I've added the following setting to my `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

But I'm getting the following information from somewhere:

```
Redirected to http://test.host/
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
Processing by UserFriendshipsController#new as HTML
```

I assume this is because these errors are also classed as `info`. Can I make my own type of log or something so I can log only what I explicitly specify?

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best answer, but definitely the easiest way to get a concise log is setting the log level to fatal and logging your variables as fatal.

Your app will rarely behave in such a way to trigger a `fatal` log (hopefully!) so I can get some really clear logs with it:

*config/environments/test.rb*

```
config.log_level = :fatal
```

*config/environments/development.rb*

```
config.log_level = :fatal
```

*Somewhere in your app directory*

```
  logger.fatal "All on my lonesome but that's a good thing"
```

Results in:

```
"All on my lonesome but that's a good thing"
```

This'll work fine for me until someone has a better solution